# Proof verification about inexistence of a surjective homomorphism between $C_8\times C_2 \to C_4 \times C_4$

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups, cyclic-groups, direct-product

> Q. Prove that there does not exist a subjective homomorphism $C_8\times C_2 \to C_4 \times C_4$

My attempt: FSOC, assume there is such a homomorphism. As $|C_8\times C_2| = |C_4 \times C_4|$, the homomorphism must be bijective and hence an isomorphism. This means the two groups are isomorphic. But this is a contradiction as the former has an element of order 8 while the latter doesn't.

Thanks in advance for your help! :)

Comment: Yeah, the linked question answers my doubt! thanks!

Comment: Should I delete my question?

Comment: You don't have to, @mathematics_2001